# Does specifying a column in sqlite3 while creating a table automatically make it distinct?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

So I have a database that includes records of purchases, and every record has a lot of columns including the id of the person buying and their name.
If I want to create a new table just for the customers, I am doing this :

```
Purchasedf = pd.read_csv('Purchase.csv')

conn = sqlite3.connect('Purchase.db')

cursor = conn.cursor()

#The Client table
cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Client (
        CustomerID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
        CustomerName TEXT,
        CustomerEmail TEXT,
        CustomerPhone TEXT
    );
''')

Purchasedf.to_sql("Client", conn, if_exists='replace')



cursor.execute('''
    SELECT CustomerID
    FROM Client
''')
display(cursor.fetchall())


conn.commit()
```

So my csv file looks like this :
First row:

```
PurchaseID,CustomerID,CustomerName,CustomerEmail,CustomerPhone,ProductID,Purchase_Date
```

Second row:

```
1,6145,Ethan Smith,ethan.smith@mail.com,555-087834,8513,2024-10-07 16:33:28.557244
```

Now if I try to Select the CustomerID from Client, I am getting repeated IDs.
How can I make them distinct? I mean I know I can select them distinctly, but shouldn't the (PRIMARY KEY) keyword make the actual table distinct with ID's?

Comment: Primary keys are always distinct, you shouldn't get any duplicates. Please post a [mre] that shows this.

Comment: Then you should show us the select code and processing as well

Comment: Is this happening as part of a `JOIN`? There could be multiple rows in the table you're joining with that relate to the same customer ID.

Comment: I updated it so it's clearer, I don't think I have an issue with my code, but I think logically I don't understand how to make a table from a database in sql.
Do I have to maybe put the values I want in another dataframe maybe?

Comment: My output looks something like this : 
(6145,),
 (6145,),
 (6145,),
 (6148,),
 (6148,),
 (6148,),.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Client table already exists from a previous run, and its CustomerID is not unique.

---

Because you're running `create table if not exists`, and you're not dropping the table, the first run of your code will create a table. That table, presumably, did not have a primary key.

Subsequent runs will ignore your `create table`, because it already exists, and reuse the existing table. It will not change the schema.

Now every time you run the code, you're inserting duplicates.

You can check by running `.schema Client` in the SQLite shell.

This sort of problem is handled in production code with a [schema migration](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) tool.

Comment: Even if I delete the previous database and rerun it still gives repeated ids.

Comment: I actually tried printing my client table, and its printing all the columns in the dataframe?

Comment: `unique_clients_df = BookingDetailsDf[['CustomerID', 'CustomerName', 'CustomerEmail', 'CustomerPhone']].drop_duplicates()

# Write the unique client information to the Client table
unique_clients_df.to_sql("Client", conn, if_exists="replace", index=False)`

I ended up doing this, but I have to make a couple more tables like this, won't it be redundant? Or is this correct way to go about something like this?

Comment: @Xayyna 1) What does `.schema Client` say? Does it show that CustomerID is the primary key? 2) Sorry, I don't know what that code does. If you're asking whether you should recreate the table every time the program is run, that depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: No, it showed that the Client table had all the columns that were in the big database.
And I was trying to make different tables out of one csv file, I found that making a separate dataframe for each table was the best approach.